# How to clear both widgets and their out by other widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I load the list of files with `checkbox` to be filtered using `ipywidgets`:

```
from ipywidgets import Checkbox, interact, Layout, Button
import ipywidgets as widgets
import glob
from traitlets import traitlets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

class LoadedButton(widgets.Button):
    def __init__(self, value=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoadedButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Create the value attribute.
        self.add_traits(value=traitlets.Any(value))

def file_list(**all_kwargs):
    cols = [k for k, v in all_kwargs.items() if v==True]
    return cols
    
def reload_files(rr):
    for c in all_files:
        c.close()
        clear_output()
    print('Unselect the csv files above *to EXCLUDE*')
    rr.value =interact(file_list, **all_kwargs)
    return rr

extension = 'csv'                # extention of file you want to read, csv, dat, etc.
all_file_list = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
all_files = [Checkbox(description=a, value=True) for a in all_file_list ]
all_kwargs = {c.description: c.value for c in all_files} 

lb = LoadedButton(description="Load/reload file list", value=None)
lb.on_click(reload_files)
display(lb)
```

I wish to overwrite the previous outputs (both widget and widget outputs) for every time I click on button created using the Button widget, but instead of overwriting it creates another instance of output. I tried both `clear_output` and `widget.close()` options, but nothing helps. I know `clear_output` is not expected to clear the widget, but I expect this to be possible using `close()`. Does anyone know how to clear/overwrite the ipywidgets as well ipywidget outputs when reloading by button?
[image: another instance of output]

Comment: Did that answer happen to work for you? If not If you would mind posting a more complete example then it will be easier to solve.

Comment: Thanks James for the answer. It didn't work and still gives the result same as the screenshot above. Sorry, I missed to include package list to be imported which is now included. Otherwise, the script was complete. Since the script is listing all the files with a certain extension (like 'csv' in my case) in the home folder, you may change this according to the file type you have at your end or can create some dummy CSV files while testing.

Comment: okay I update my answer I think that it may work for you now.

Comment: Thanks, I also read that `display` function causes the problem as you also found out. But the suggested solution now freezes ipywidgets checklist items, i.e., even when the csv files are replaced by new ones in the directory the displayed list of files remains the same in the notebook. It just appends "Reloading..." every time I click on reload button without replacing the existing list with new file names.

Comment: Okay just updated I think I nailed it this time.

Comment: Word thanks for accepting the answer. This is neat lil' design pattern. people will probs use it down the line. Also you should throw your dawg an upvote ;) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly I think that this might work for you;

```py
from ipywidgets import Checkbox, interact, Layout, Button
import ipywidgets as widgets
import glob
from traitlets import traitlets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

class LoadedButton(widgets.Button):
    def __init__(self, value=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoadedButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Create the value attribute.
        self.add_traits(value=traitlets.Any(value))

def file_list(**all_kwargs):
    cols = [k for k, v in all_kwargs.items() if v==True]
    return cols

def reload_files(rr):
    if rr.value is not None:
        # print("Reloading...")
        # Reset the panel to just the button.
        panel.children = [panel.children[0]]
        rr.value = None

    if rr.value is None:
        extension = 'csv' # extention of file you want to read, csv, dat, etc.
        all_file_list = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
        all_files = [Checkbox(description=a, value=True) for a in all_file_list ]
        all_kwargs = {c.description: c.value for c in all_files} 

        rr.value=widgets.interactive(file_list, **all_kwargs)
        panel.children += (rr.value,)
        # display(rr.value)


lb = LoadedButton(description="Load/reload file list", value=None)
lb.on_click(reload_files)

# A VBox for the Button and checkboxes.
panel = widgets.VBox([lb])
panel
```

I think that the problem was coming from relying on the `display` function to represent the widget. When you have one widget modified the visibilty of another the best thing that you could probably do is add and remove them from a layout widget like `VBox` or `HBox`. Either way let me know how it works out.

Update:

`glob` and all other file name operations also need to update when the button is clicked. so it does that now.

Also here is how to access the checkboxes on the `interactive` widget';

`panel.children[1].children`

OR

`lb.value.children`

Both statements refer to the same object.

Comment: There is an extra `Output` object in the widget list which I think comes from `Button`, so to access the checkboxes I had to read it like `lb.value.children[:-1]`.Otherwise, the primary task which was the real challenge now works perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: My pleasure @Ashish this was a fun problem to kick around during breaks. If you like working with ipywidgets you should look into Bokeh, Veax, ipyvolume, and nglview as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Indeed I like ipywigets and I know Bokeh, but Beax, ipyvolume, and nglview will be new thing to explore for me. :-)